# settings.bundle for preinstalled applications like mobile.safari ,mobile mail and so on

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

Does enybody know where can I find settings bundle for preinstalled applications like mobile safari, mail and so on?

I have jailbroken ios device.

I have installed my application to `/Applcation` folder. Not to the standart applications folder `/private/var/mobile/Applications`.
Therefore my settings.bundle was ignored by the system and I don't see my setting in "system settings" application.

I put my app to `/Application` to pretect my application from deletion by long push on the app icon. ( cydia installed in the same folder, and also can't be removed)

I case of regular install to `/private/var/mobile/Applications` i see my settings in "system settings" application and everything is OK.

I don't see `settings.bundle` in the `/Application/MobileSafari.app` or in the `/Applications/MobileMail.app` 
They use another way. 
And the question is how they do it? Where is they settings.bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting question, but I don't think they have a `settings.bundle`. It's probably preinstalled in the settings app or another way completely. They don't have to have a separate setting for each app, as they're all bundled together. I would search through the Settings.app if it exists (mine isn't currently jailbroken so I can't check) and/or folders in `/var`. Good luck!